# Unwanted Extra Circles in Tikz Neural Network (LaTeX)

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

Using this code, the output is as follows. Why are there extra empty circles appearing in my input layer and how do I get rid of them?

Bonus points: how could I go about overlaying weight and bias matrices in between the layers?

```
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
         % define styles 
     clear/.style={ 
         draw=none,
         fill=none
     },
     net/.style={
         matrix of nodes,
         nodes={ draw, circle, inner sep=10pt },
         %nodes in empty cells,
         column sep=2cm,
         row sep=-9pt
     },
     >=latex
]


\matrix[net] (mat)
{
|[clear]| \parbox{1.3cm}{\centering Input\\layer} 
    & |[clear]| \parbox{1.3cm}{\centering Hidden\\layer 1} 
    & |[clear]| \parbox{1.3cm}{\centering Hidden\\layer 2} 
    & |[clear]| \parbox{1.3cm}{\centering Output\\layer} \\
         
    & 10 (on)   \\

2  &                 & 13 (on) \\

     & 0 (off)   &                  & 1 \\

1  &                 & 0 (off)        \\

    & 1 (on)     \\
}
;

\foreach \ai in {3, 5} {
            \foreach \aii in {2,4,6}
                \draw[->] (mat-\ai-1) -- (mat-\aii-2);
                }
                
\foreach \ai in {2, 4, 6} {
            \foreach \aii in {3, 5}
                \draw[->] (mat-\ai-2) -- (mat-\aii-3);
                }
                
\foreach \ai in {3, 5} {
            \foreach \aii in {4}
                \draw[->] (mat-\ai-3) -- (mat-\aii-4);
                }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Culprit are empty lines in your `matrix`. Delete them. Off.topic, you can make more concise code, for example as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
         % define styles
net/.style={matrix of nodes,
            nodes = {circle, draw, text width=2.4em, align=center,
                     inner sep=0pt, anchor=center},
            row 1/.style = {nodes={rectangle, draw=none,
                            text width=4em, align=center,
                            inner sep=0pt, anchor=center}},
            column sep=12mm,
            row sep=6pt
            },
     >=latex
                    ]
\matrix[net] (mat)
{
Input layer
    & Hidden layer 1
                & Hidden layer 2
                            & Output layer \\
    & 10 (on)   &           &   \\
2   &           & 13 (on)   &   \\
    & 0 (off)   &           & 1 \\
1   &           & 0 (off)   &   \\
    & 1 (on)    &           &   \\
};

\foreach \ai in {3, 5} {
            \foreach \aii in {2,4,6}
                \draw[->] (mat-\ai-1) -- (mat-\aii-2);
                }

\foreach \ai in {2, 4, 6} {
            \foreach \aii in {3, 5}
                \draw[->] (mat-\ai-2) -- (mat-\aii-3);
                }

\foreach \ai in {3, 5} {
            \foreach \aii in {4}
                \draw[->] (mat-\ai-3) -- (mat-\aii-4);
                }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produce

[image]